# Add button link in silverstripe

Tags: button, hyperlink, silverstripe

i am validating my email field checking if the email in the database. and if so gives a message. this is the first page of my multiform. i need to showup a button on my 1st page only if the email available in my db to directly login to the system. how could i do this. button is only a link to another page.
in my ss file;

$MemberRegistrationMultiForm

```
        <p>This email has been used</p>
         <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="{$BaseHref}myaccount">Login</a></p>
        <% end_if %>
```

Comment: i could imagine something with some kind of ajax field (similar to urlfield in cms which updates url and checks if url exists) in combination with unclecheese's display logic module https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic

Answer (score 1):

i removed above codes and did a validation in my page, i extended the requiredfield class as Email_Validator and call it in my original class. this bring the validation. i need to add login button if the email address exist in the db, how could i do that part

class Email_Validator extends RequiredFields {

```
public function php($data){
    $bRet = parent::php($data);
    if($bRet){
        $customer = Customer::get()->filter('Email', $data['Email'])->first();
        if($customer){
            $this->validationError('Email', 'This email has been used ', 'bad');
            //$bRet ="<p><a class='btn btn-warning' href=".Director::baseURL() . "myaccount/>Login to my account</a></p>";
           $bRet = false;

        }

    }
    return $bRet;
}
```

}